# PAM and fprintd

Tags: ubuntu, pam, unity

Occasionally I get an error on the login screen of Ubuntu 14.04 under unity. The problem occurs after waking up from suspend after closing the lid. Essentially instead of asking me first for fingerprint and if it times out for password, initially there is no field to write the password nor there is any prompt for fingerprint. After ~30-40s only password field is shown (note the usual timeout of the fingerprint is 10s). I enabled debug on the PAM module and got this:

unity[2100]: pam_fprintd(unity): get_devices failed: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.

Any idea what exactly is causing (I understand it is something connected with fprintd, but what) and potentially how I could fix this.